# EJB-Annotations Questions

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, ejb, javabeans

I'm new to JavaEE and EJBs.
I made my first few steps with it but there are quite a few things about the basic annotations, that I don't get, no matter how much time i spend googling and reading E-Books.
Maybe someone can help out or refer me to a good explanation.

@Stateful/@Stateless
I think I understood the basic concept. But which one is used by default?

@ManagedBean/@Named
Is the @Named Annotaion same as @ManagedBean simply with a custom Name?

@Sessionscoped/@Requestscoped
Do these interfere with @Stateful/@Stateless?
In my understanding it wouldn't make sense to pair @Stateless with @Sessionscoped, because @Stateless beans are in this "Bean-Pool" on the server and are for Single-Method-Invocations and not for enduring tasks. Based on this logic I'd argue that it doesn't make sense to have a @Requestscoped @Stateful bean, because after the initial HTTP-Request your Bean is "disconnected" from the client.

I get my Programs to work, but how can I now if I did it efficient, if I actually have no idea what I'm doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AD 1. None is the "default". An EJB must be declared as an EJB and you do it either by annotating it with `@Stateless`, `@Stateful`, `@Singleton`, `@MessageDriven`.

If you don't have any of them than it's not an EJB, so there is no way to define a "default" value.

AD 2. There are two `@ManagedBean` in the matter of fact: [javax.faces one](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html) and [javax.annotation one](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/annotation/ManagedBean.html)

Frankly, I don't know where the `@ManagedBean` from `javax.annotation` is really used. It declares that the bean is *managed* by the container, so its lifecycle is controlled - but what container controls it? I somehow feels that it's obsolete as there are `@Named`, `javax.faces @ManagedBean`, EJB's annotations and CDI annotations - all of them defines their annotated classes as *managed* but clearly defines container that manages them.

`@Named` defines a CDI bean that can be used e.g. in the JSF views (UEL expressions). `@ManagedBean` defines a JSF managed bean. Often they can be used interchangeably but there are some differences you should be aware of, e.g. `@Named` bean you use cannot be annotated as JSF `@ViewScoped` as `@ViewScoped` can only be applied to the JSF managed bean.

AD 3. I don't think you should mix CDI scopes with EJB scopes. That's something that is often confused and it would be great if future Java EE address this issue.

EJB beans (`@Stateless`/`@Stateful`) got their own lifecycles and CDI beans (`@SessionScoped`, `@RequestScoped`) got their own.
I am not sure what you'd get by mixing those annotations - perhaps an exception, maybe some black-magic bugs or it might actually work as you wanted.
I guess it's totally implementor-dependent as I don't recall its defined in the EJB / CDI specification. I would not depend on it.

Comment: Thank you, that really cleared things up!
I always thought this must be really easy, but somehow I must have overread how those annotations relate to each other.

Comment: Glad I could help you :-) Well, I find those things really messed up if you're just starting with Java EE and I really hope future Java EE would fix those things (like scopes). E.g. there could be a CDI sitting in the core and all other containers use specialized stereotypes, like EJB would be just a CDI with `@RequestScoped`, `@Transactional`. Nevertheless, sometimes it's hard to get answers for simple questions :-) Cheers!